# Editing Filemaker Custom Menu to Show Custom Name in Application menu

Tags: filemaker

How do you edit the application menu of a Filemaker solution to show the name of the client company or your application name instead of "Filemaker Pro"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. This menu and Tools menu in Advanced are always present and not editable. Also, you can't remove Help menu, although you can remove all items.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind your solution as a Runtime, then it will display your application name instead of FileMaker. Otherwise, your solution is still running in FileMaker Pro and it probably should display, right?